# How do you automatically import java libraries in sublime text 3?

Tags: java, json, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm not even sure if library is the right term but I mean the things you put at the start of the code like this: "import javax.swing.JFrame;". I wanted a thing that would automatically put those in at the start of my code so I downloaded the JavaImports package from here: 
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JavaImports

I went into sublime text 3 settings and in the right hand side panel, I pasted in this code:

```
"settings":
{
"java_import_path":
[
    "default/java/import/path/src.zip",
    "path/to/library.jar"
]
}
```

However, this gave me errors saying there were trailing characters so I removed the curly braces and the word "settings":. I saved it and went into some java code in sublime text and pressed Ctrl + Alt + i and in the console, it said this:

```
File "./python3.3/zipfile.py", line 921, in __init__
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'default/java/import/path/src.zip'
```

I'd be very grateful if you could tell me how to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: Is `default/java/import/path/src.zip` a valid path on your computer where you have stored a zip file with the classes which you want to import? Those path names in the example are just examples, you have to replace them with the locations of your source or Jar files of the libraries which you want to use. Besides that, you could also just use an IDE and have all that for free.

Comment: you want to import java classes but you are using a python script , how is that possible?

Comment: I think the problem is that that filepath doesn't exist but I tried looking for a zip file full of classes and I don't really even know what it is or if it exists. I think I will just use another IDE. Sublime text is way too hard to use for a novice. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it said to add:

```
"settings":
{
    "java_import_path":
    [
        "default/java/import/path/src.zip",
        "path/to/library.jar"
    ]
}
```

It wasn't being literal. Those files won't exist on your computer.

What you want to do is go into your JDK directory and find your `src.zip` filepath. Then put that in the settings. For me, this would be:

```
"settings":
{
    "java_import_path":
    [
        "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/src.zip"
    ]
}
```

But I'm on a Mac and yours is probably different.

Comment: No problem. Could you accept the answer if it worked out for you?

Comment: Note that you will have to manually download and add all source jars for your project dependencies which is quite a hassle